# How to understand CoreData's parent/child model in Apple's document?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

Let's see Apple's document about CoreData's Concurrency:

> In general, avoid doing data processing on the main queue that is not user-related. Data processing can be CPU-intensive, and if it is performed on the main queue, it can result in unresponsiveness in the user interface. If your application will be processing data, such as importing data into Core Data from JSON, create a private queue context and perform the import on the private context. The following example shows how to do this:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = …; //JSON data to be imported into Core Data
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = …; //Our primary context on the mainqueue


NSManagedObjectContext *private = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[private setParentContext:moc];

[private performBlock:^{
for (NSDictionary *jsonObject in jsonArray) {
    NSManagedObject *mo = …; //Managed object that matches the incoming JSON structure
    //update MO with data from the dictionary
}
NSError *error = nil;
if (![private save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error saving context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
}];
```

According the code, I think it will block the main queue if the main queue context is the root context. I think the context in the private queue should be the root context, and the main queue's Context is the child context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> According the code, I think it will block the main queue, because the parent context is in the main queue.

No, it won't, at least not in the code shown. The data will process on a background thread and be pushed into the main thread context when the private context is saved (note that doesn't save it to disk).

> I think the context in the private queue should be the parent context, and the mainContext is the child context

This part is interesting, because the example should really go further... If the main thread context is the root context then any saves to disk will run on the main thread. Not clear if that's what you mean, but it looks like it.

So, yes, you should really have a private queue context as the root connected to the PSC, then the main as a child of that. The importing private queue contexts are generally then children of main, but they can be siblings instead. If you choose the sibling route it minimises main thread time but means you need to deal with merging changes to the main thread context yourself...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. in my question, i mean it will block the main queue if the main queue context is the root context. is it right?

Comment: only when you save the main thread context because that would write the data to disk (if the main thread context is the root and connected to the PSC). it won't block main when you save the child, well, maybe a tiny bit when it merges...

Comment: you mean when I save the child's context, it will  only merge the change to parent  context, but won't save the change to the disk? if I want to save changes to disk, I must save the root context manually.does I understand your thinking correctly?

Comment: you must save all parents in turn up to the root, a child save will save that child and merge to parent but that's it

Comment: oh, Thank you very much. you resolve the problem which troubles me very long time.